# Assembly is located at bad address - Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, apk, hockeyapp

I am distributing an android .apk file to a beta test group set using Hockey App.  When a user clicks the "Open" button after the download and installation process, the application loads for less than a second and disappears like it has crashed.  When the users bring up the running application queue, you can see my application with a blank black screen.

I was able to attach a test Android device to my workstation and ran the Android Device Logging with the Xamarin Visual Studio plug in while trying to follow the process used by our testers.

The following errors show up in the device log when the application "crashed" on my test device:

> - E 1442 monodroid-assembly Assembly
>     'assemblies/MyAndroidProject.dll.config' is located at a bad address
>     0x54622c3a
> - E 1442 monodroid-assembly You MUST run 'zipalign' on
>     myapp.myapp-1.apk
> - I 914 ActivityManager Process myapp.myapp (pid 1442)
>     has died

Any idea how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

This was caused by my .apk file not being zipaligned after I signed the .apk file with the custom keystore created for the Android application.